# How to monitor the files Generated during a Setup

Tags: c#, winforms, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to develop a tool which monitors the files generated during running setup files of some windows drivers. I tried using the simple code.
 "The thread '' (0x29e8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '' (0xe3c) has exited with code 0 (0x0)."

But its just giving this as output in console.
I am not able to get the changes of files being created at the directory. Please help.

```
   public void StartFileSystemWatcher()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

        // Set folder path to watch
        fileSystemWatcher.Path = "C:\\";
        fileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        fileSystemWatcher.Filter = "*.exe|*.dll|*.ini|*.sys|*.cpl|*.inf|*.pbk|*.cat";
        fileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter = System.IO.NotifyFilters.FileName |
            System.IO.NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
            System.IO.NotifyFilters.Size |
            System.IO.NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;


        // Event handlers that are watching for specific event
        fileSystemWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(fileSystemWatcher_Created);
        fileSystemWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(fileSystemWatcher_Changed);
        fileSystemWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(fileSystemWatcher_Deleted);
        fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(fileSystemWatcher_Renamed);
        // START watching
        fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

        void fileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File:" + e.ChangeType + " " + e.Name);
    }
```

Comment: try running the program with administrator account

Comment: Just confirmation please: is this a Console application or a WinForms application? Your application is exiting before the FileSystemWatcher is able to fire any events, which makes me think you're running a Console app - though you have the question tagged `WinForms`.

Comment: Hi Anthony, Its a Winform Application. I am just using console to watch the changes whatever being occured during setup.